# Display details stored in address book while receiving a call

Tags: contacts, phone-app, caller-id

Let's consider a situation where I have lot of people in my contact list named Kumar. Is there a way to display all or some of the details stored in address of a contact while receiving a call? like his company, address, anniversaries, etc,.

Comment: I found an app. But looking for better options and preferably free ones. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nikanorov.callnotespro&hl=en_IN

Comment: I'm running Android 10 on Redmi Mi A3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[True Phone Dialer & Contacts & Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hb.dialer.free) is a contacts and dialer app that does pretty much what you are looking for except displaying email ID. It's free for 7 days after which you can disable ads by going pro.

Install the app, from 3 dots menu at bottom right → Incoming /Outgoing Calls → disable incoming call notification to see full screen call details.

On my OnePlus 7, Android 10,using the default contact app I filled in details and it displays event date (birthday), address & notes ( Don't be Covidiot- you can replace this by Email address if you badly need that)

[image: IMG:]

(Click to enlarge)

From 3 dots menu at bottom right → Incoming /Outgoing Calls →  additional info, select to show (needs to be manually edited in the contact information using this app)

[image: IMG:]

(Click to enlarge)

I added *job information* & *Nickname* manually (my contacts app doesn't have those fields) and now the screen shows

[image: IMG:]

(Click to enlarge)

[Eyecon:caller ID, calls and phone contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eyecon.global) is another alternative that harvests caller information and photos from social media and displays - in case, it helps somebody who likes that approach.